# Sign-in to my app using Google also signs in user to Google services like gmail

Tags: google-signin

I'm using Google OAuth2 to integrate Google Signin to my app. I'm referring [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/) documentation for the same.

Everything is working as expected, but I'm noticing a behavior which seems odd to me. That is,

- I make sure that I'm not currently logged into any of google accounts
- I launch my web app which has google sign in integrated and I click on google sign in button in my app and google prompts me for credentials in a popup.
- Login succeeds and I'm logged into my app now.

Now, in a new tab of the browser I open gmail.com and I am taken directly to my inbox of the account which I used to login to my web app previously.

Is this behavior part of Google or OAuth2 spec?

The problem I'm facing because of this is, user signs out of my web-app and leaves. Now another user comes and just opens gmail.com and this new user is landed directly into the previous user's mailbox.

How can I prevent either logging into google services while logging into my app or logout of google services when user logs out of my web app?

I believe the 2nd option will be a bad experience for user and I'm looking to find why in first place the user is logged into google services while they are trying to log into my web app only?

Please guide.

Comment: This is the current intended behaviour: signing into a service with Google enables the Google Account in the browser/device. What's the nature of your app? Why are people switching between accounts on the same device?

Comment: @StevenSoneff I have a web app with google sign in integrated. The app is targeted for laptops/desktops. The user launches app, logs in using google, uses the app and they will sign out from the app using sign out button provided within the app. But the user is unaware that they are logged out of ONLY the app and their session with google services is still active. If its a shared computer, then if next user opens any google services, he has access to previous users google account. Isn't it?

Comment: We have a similar problem with device wide access, but it's only when users sign in using a native Android app.

In our web app we have implemented a solution that signs the user out across browser tabs by directing the user to: `https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue=https://www.yoursite.com`

The magic happens in the `https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout` redirect.